# Can I create an index on maps in Scylla DB?

Tags: json, indexing, scylla

There is a native map type in Scylla DB https://docs.scylladb.com/getting-started/types/#maps Is it possible to create an index on it? So it would be somewhat like GIN in PostgreSQL.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since `maps` are a type of collection, I think this GH issue pretty much sums it and what's supported (or not). https://github.com/scylladb/scylla/issues/3654#issuecomment-479639450

Validations req mentioned in the GH issue:

> - disallow FULL indexes on non-frozen collections
> - disallow non-FULL indexes on frozen collections
> - disallow repeated creation of FULL indexes on the same collection
> - disallow referencing frozen-map entries in the WHERE clause (only allow complete map values)

What we have:

> Non-frozen collections are currently not supported at all with proper error message, non-full indexes on frozen collections are also disallowed, repeated creation is by default forbidden for any index too.
> Also, I think that referencing frozen-map entries in WHERE clause should be allowed, at least with filtering.

If you find any different behavior, please let us know and file a GH issue.

Comment: Thank you TomerSan! I wasn't able to find the documentation explaining the difference between FULL and non-FULL indexes but as it can be inferred from the name FULL index is exactly what I'm looking for and my collection is non-frozen. Considering that FULL index for such collections is not allowed and they can't be referenced in WHERE clause it won't work in my case. Actually it seems that Scylla may not be the best choice if some needs to store JSON-like documents in the DB along with columnar data